# If statement gets executed, even though it is not true

Tags: objective-c

first of all, I'm only a hobby programmer and just started to learn Objective-C.
However, yesterday I was working on a challenge from a book that covers Objective-C.

Somehow, and I simply cannot find the mistake, an if-statement gets executed, even though it is not true.

```
  if (subString) {
        NSUInteger index = [brandList indexOfObject:subString];
        // Did parse fail?
        if (index == NSNotFound) {
            if (error) {
                NSDictionary *userInfo = @{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: @"Unable to parse"};
                *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"SpeakableBytes" code:1 userInfo:userInfo];
                return nil;
            }
        }
        sum |= index;
        [output appendBytes:&sum length:sizeof(unsigned char)];
    }
```

My program executes `return nil`even though index != NSNotFound. However, only the return statement gets executed, everything else not. I guess I simply made a silly mistake which I cannot find.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: How do you know that `return nil` gets executed? Is this what's get returned? Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: How do you know it is that return? What if `subString` evaluates to `false` and you fall through to something below?

Comment: How do you know this is what's happening -- is it based on stepping through in the debugger? If so, be aware that the debugger sometimes makes it look like things are happening (particularly return statements) that are not, due to optimizations in code generation.

Comment: Are you sure it's _that_ `return nil` that gets executed?

Comment: This is what the debugger is for. Step through the code line by line and look at each value and see which code is executed. This is the proper way to be sure about what is going on and why.

Comment: Please provide the rest of the code, with only this part of code it is not easy to help you. Also add an NSLog() before return nil to check if this is really the part of code that is being executed.

Comment: I debugged the code and found my silly mistake. It had nothing to do with the return statement. Both if-statements and the variable initialization changed the default length value of a NSRange object after declaration. This in turn had an influence on the while loop which included the rest of my code. A typical beginner's mistake, but that's the only way to improve myself.

I apologize for any inconvenience and thanks for all the fast answers.